# FragmentStatePagerAdapter / Update Action Bar Title

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I have my host activity with a ViewPager+FragmentStatePagerAdapter which let me swipe through a set of fragments (different instances of the same ItemFragment class) and the data for populating each fragment are fetched from the network.

Now, while I swipe I want to update the action bar title with a property coming from the current fragment so I use OnPageChangeListener/onPageSelected to do that work:

```
...
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    MyFragment currentFragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.view_pager);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(currentFragment.propertyIWantToUseAsTitle);
}
...
```

I have couple of doubts here:

- am I retrieving the real current fragment? The FragmentStatePageAdapter does not set a tag for each fragment so I don't know any other way to get the current fragment rather than using the ViewGroup container
- when onPageSelected is invoked, the added fragment could be still fetching the data I need to set the action bar title causing a npe.

What's the best place to keep the logic of updating the action bar title in the scenario described above?

ps. I have tried a mixed approach adding to MyFragment the code to update the ab when the data I need are available. The problem is that few fragments are loaded ahead having the action bar title changing as the fragments finish loading. The result is the ab title is a random title coming from a fragment few pages ahead.

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: "am I retrieving the real current fragment?" -- perhaps now, but you are dependent upon `ViewPager` implementation details, which is risky. "The FragmentStatePageAdapter does not set a tag for each fragment" -- are you limited to using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`? "What's the best place to keep the logic of updating the action bar title in the scenario described above?" -- yeah, I really need to work out a solution for this. It's now officially on my to-do list.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I just made it work but I am concerned about memory usage. Take a look here https://gist.github.com/gwvatieri/5544164

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, your `PagerAdapter` should be called with `setPrimaryItem()` when a new page is set to be "current". You could override that method, chain to the superclass, then cast the `Object` (first parameter to `setPrimaryItem()`) to your appropriate `Fragment` class and do something with it. That "something" could be stashing it in a data member of your `PagerAdapter` (e.g., `currentPage`) and adding a getter to be able to retrieve it later.

Comment: Did a quick test, for some reasons the onPageSelected callback is sometime fired earlier than setPrimaryItem causing the action bar having the title of the prev or next item. Plus there's a delay caused by the call to setPrimaryItem (by the way it's fired multiple times)...

Comment: @gwa: "for some reasons the onPageSelected callback is sometime fired earlier than setPrimaryItem causing the action bar having the title of the prev or next item" -- so? Update the action bar from `setPrimaryItem()`. I'm afraid that I didn't follow the rest of your comment.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense, just removed the map keeping the references to fragments. Thanks for helping. Are you gonna be at the IO next week?

Comment: @gwa: No. In part, that's because I wasn't available during the 57 milliseconds when tickets were available... :-)

Answer (score 3):

I set the `ActionBar` title in the `Fragment` itself.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    type = (String) extras.getString("type");
}// end method

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        Activity activity =  getActivity();
        ActionBar actionBar = activity.getActionBar();

        if (type.equals("one")) {
            actionBar.setTitle(R.string.one);
        }
        if (type.equals("two")) {
            actionBar.setTitle(R.string.two);
        }
        if (type.equals("three")) {
            actionBar.setTitle(R.string.three);
        }
    } 
}//end method
```